# What do I make of this error dialog in mac?

Tags: macos

I get this error dialog while opening a ".app" file. This .app file has same contents as another copy of ".app", at least comparing the .app files using FileMerge. Why does this dialog supposed to come up.
[image]

Attaching the apps here:

1. App with error:
   https://hightailspaces.com/space/6KRLl
2. App which works:
   https://hightailspaces.com/space/9TNiO

Comment: why is the application name blocked out? try opening as an admin aka right click and click open

Comment: That's a different dialog when it says .app is downloaded from Internet. This is a different error. And application name is deliberately hidden.

Comment: ... is that System 7, 8 or 9? It *looks* pre OSX there.

Comment: It's OSX Yosemite: 10.10.2

Comment: What is the original name of the app and where is it from?

Comment: Attached sample apps in description. Pls check

Comment: I don't think anyone's going to open those apps. How can they know those will not wipe out their entire hard drive or something?

Comment: Also, maybe include some code or error message as this might otherwise be considered off-topic for StackOverflow :)

Comment: @zenith, I'd say that the alert shown in a screen shot is an error message.  The fact that it's not very informative is Apple's fault, not the poster's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the one with the error, the executable file does not have its executable bit set.

There are also problems with the Info.plist in both files, such as CFBundleExecutable not being specified.

Comment: Yeah .. I think you're right. The executable bit was not set on the executable file inside the app package. Thanks for the input.